# Does Cross Join not work between two different tables with same column name?

Tags: mysql, database, cross-join, cartesian

As written on the title, does CROSS JOIN not work for different tables with the same column name?

For example,
I have one table named Fruits:

```
|  name  |  price  |
|  apple |    1    |
| banana |    2    |
```

and another table named Snacks:

```
|  name   |  price  |
|  chips  |    3    |
| cookies |    4    |
```

Then does

```
SELECT Fruits.price, Snacks.price FROM Fruits CROSS JOIN Snacks
```

does not work properly?
I am working on a same issue, but the result shows like:

```
|  price  |  price  |
|    3    |    3    |
|    4    |    4    |
|    3    |    3    |
|    4    |    4    |
```

But what I expect is:

```
|  price  |  price  |
|    1    |    3    |
|    1    |    4    |
|    2    |    3    |
|    2    |    4    |
```

Comment: Not Possible. Probably your fruits table has 3,4 values. Show your exact data from both tables and select result.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, it is not possible. Either your tables values are different or your query.

Check this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=3fc64a952d59a9fdd4367dbb9f3ecbae) showing the result value same as your expected values.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL `CROSS JOIN` works as expected:

```
 price  price 
 ------ ----- 
 1      3     
 2      3     
 1      4     
 2      4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hYYzyMFpM5cb6AArw2GT6/0).